# Apache redirects directories

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

So, I'm trying to redirect any pages to a file, but avoid redirecting anything thats an existing file or directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  $1 [L]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$  /index.php?page=$1 [QSA]
```

However, any directories still get redirected (existing files are fine and can be located.)

Comment: are you asking how to redirect any file (but not directory) requests that don't exist?

Answer (score 1):

You're using REQUEST_FILENAME to mean REQUEST_URI, and while that is documented to work in some cases (like when used on a vhost), I have a feeling that in this case it's already determined into the final name. See if `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d` makes a difference, or just always use REQUEST_URI.

If not, well, one option is to rewrite to add index.htm/html/php/pl etc to the end, test each for existence and finalize the rule if so, otherwise go to the last step? That's all that I can think of off the top of my head.